# Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause in Max statement inside a function

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb, string-concatenation, oledbcommand

I am trying to simply connect to a database. But the problem arises in the concatenation part of the Sql query.

When I do:

```
 cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from Table1", con)
```

There is no error but when I do

```
 cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from'" & tablename & "'", con)
```

The vb.net error comes: **Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause.**

Here is the full code

```
Function Get_Max(ByVal Get_Table_Name As String)
    Dim tablename As String = Get_Table_Name
    Dim found_max As Integer
    Call connect()
    con.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from'" & tablename & "'", con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        found_max = dr(0)
    End While
    con.Close()
    MsgBox(found_max)

    Return found_max

End Function
```

Comment: When I debug the Variable tablename has the String "Table1" inside but there must a problem with the concatenation

Comment: Do not quote the table name when concatenating, if you must, use square brackets around the table name. Max(ID) is extremely unsafe.

Comment: I am just learning. After this I will switch to Paramatized and try again. Thanks to all

Comment: Well, good intention, but you cannot parameterize the table or the field's names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not put single quotes around the variable tablename

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from " & tablename, con)
```

Otherwise the tablename variable becomes a literal string and, from the database point of view you are requesting the MAX(ID) of the string `'Table1'`.

A part from this you should be absolutely sure about the value of the variable `tablename`.

Do not allow the end user to directly type this value (at least let him choose between a list of predefined names).
This kind of code is very weak and open to Sql Injections.

And, as other answers have already outlined, a couple of Square Brackets around the table name are required if one or more of your tables contains a space or have the same name as a reserved keyword

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from [" & tablename & "]", con)
```

Comment: Any resources on where to learn all of these commas and concatenations
I need to know this

Comment: Just basic rules of any SQL dialect - You could [try this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp), but it is very basic

Comment: Steve, I have said this twice, but I really must say it again. Max(ID) is extremely unsafe and should not be used to get the last ID.

Comment: @Remou also in case of single thread, single user? Not to refute your argument (I agree with you) but just to know your opinion.

Comment: @Steve, not usually for a single user, although it is possible to create a problem on a single pc, but is a single user likely when vb,net is being used? Also if it is a single user, sql injection is not a problem :)

Comment: Yes, users have always a way to mess things up. I would like to know better the context of this code because I smell fishy when I see a table name concatenated to form a query

Comment: I am trying paramatized version and same eror comes up

                                                                  cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from @CustName", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", tablename)


any ideas?

Comment: No, you can't use a parameter to express a table name or a field name. Parameters could only be used for values in WHERE statements or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

Answer (score 2):

change this line

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from " & tablename & "", con)
```

to this

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from " & tablename, con)
```

you just missed a space and remove the "'"

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but that does not solve it yet

Answer (score 2):

You are adding in additional quote characters. Your initial string

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from'" & tablename & "'", con)
```

is evaluating to

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from'Table1'", con)
```

Instead, you should probably be using:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select max(ID) from [" & tablename & "]", con)
```

The `[` and `]` give you additional protection against reserved words matching table names, although not SQL query injection, to which this code may still be vulnerable.

Comment: You may need square brackets. Max(ID) is nearly always a very bad idea.

Comment: @Remou I agree; I'd always use `identity_insert` myself.

Comment: That will not work in MS Access, but @@identity will.